# Coq: why do I need to manually unfold a value even though it has a `Hint Unfold` on it?

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

I've come up with the following toy proof script:

```
Inductive myType : Type :=
| c : unit -> myType.

Inductive myProp : myType -> Type :=
| d : forall t, myProp (c t).
Hint Constructors myProp.

Definition myValue : myType := c tt.
Hint Unfold myValue.

Example test: myProp myValue.
Proof.
  auto 1000. (* does nothing *)
  unfold myValue.
  trivial.
Qed.
```

Why do I need to manually unfold `myValue` here? Shouldn't the hint suffice?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because (see [refman](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proofs/automatic-tactics/auto.html#coq:cmd.Hint-Unfold))

> This [`Hint Unfold <qualid>`] adds the tactic `unfold qualid` to the hint list that will only be used when the head constant of the goal is ident.

And the goal `myProp myValue` has `myProp` in the head position, not `myValue`.

There are several ways of dealing with this:

```
Hint Extern 4 => constructor.   (* change 4 with a cost of your choice *)
```

or

```
Hint Extern 4 => unfold myValue.
```

or even

```
Hint Extern 1 =>
  match goal with
  | [ |- context [myValue]] => unfold myValue
  end.
```

Answer (score 4):

@AntonTrunov is correct in his explanation on why [`Hint Unfold`](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proofs/automatic-tactics/auto.html#coq:cmd.Hint-Unfold) is not used here. There is the alternative [`Hint Transparent`](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proofs/automatic-tactics/auto.html#coq:cmd.Hint-Transparent) that makes the application work modulo delta for some specific constants. It seems not to be yet supported by [`trivial`](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proofs/automatic-tactics/auto.html#coq:tacn.trivial) and [`auto`](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proofs/automatic-tactics/auto.html#coq:tacn.auto) but is supported by [`eauto`](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proofs/automatic-tactics/auto.html#coq:tacn.eauto) as you can see in the following:

```
Inductive myType : Type :=
| c : unit -> myType.

Inductive myProp : myType -> Type :=
| d : forall t, myProp (c t).
Hint Constructors myProp.

Definition myValue : myType := c tt.
Hint Transparent myValue.

Example test: myProp myValue.
Proof.
  eauto.
Qed.
```